# catch statement executing when try is successful how to fix

Tags: java, try-catch

Hello I am just starting to learn java and I ran into this issue with a project.
My try.catch statement is to check if a new phone number contains only digits and is 10 characters in length.

```
public void setBusinessPhone(String newBusinessPhone) {
    int numberTest;//Used to test if the new number contains any non digit characters.

    if (newBusinessPhone.length() != 10) { //test to see if the phone number is 10 characters in length.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Phone number must be 10 digits in length.");
    }

    try { //Test if the new phone number contains any non numeric characters.
        numberTest = Integer.parseInt(newBusinessPhone);
    }
    catch ( NumberFormatException e) { //Number contains invalid characters print an error message to the user.
        System.out.println("Not a legal phone number. Please enter a phone number 10 digits in length and only contains digits 0-9.");
    }
    businessPhone = newBusinessPhone;

}
```

When the try statement executes successfully the catch statement will still execute. How do I have the code only execute the catch statement when the try statement runs into an exception. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `newBusinessPhone` that throws the exception?

Comment: No, the catch doesn’t get executed unless the try block throws something. Add a println to show the exception.

Comment: If you're trying to parse a phone number with braces, dashes, and spaces, that will fail. You can't parse that as a number.

Comment: This is probably failing because your number exceeds the bounds of an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the java api the Integer.parseInt(newBusinessPhone) calls this method

```
  public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return parseInt(s,10);
  }
```

inside parseInt(s,10) where var s is your newBusinessPhone the api says that the number cannot be bigger than 2147483647  example parseInt("2147483648", 10) throws a NumberFormatException, solution use Long.parseUnsignedLong(newBusinessPhone) and use long.

```
public void setBusinessPhone(String newBusinessPhone) {
    long numberTest;//Used to test if the new number contains any non digit characters.

    if (newBusinessPhone.length() != 10) { //test to see if the phone number is 10 characters in length.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Phone number must be 10 digits in length.");
    }

    try { //Test if the new phone number contains any non numeric characters.
        numberTest = Long.parseUnsignedLong(newBusinessPhone);
    }
    catch ( NumberFormatException e) { //Number contains invalid characters print an error message to the user.
        System.out.println("Not a legal phone number. Please enter a phone number 10 digits in length and only contains digits 0-9.");
    }
    businessPhone = newBusinessPhone;

}
```

, best regards.